# If $f$ is a strictly-increasing differentiable function, how can we characterise the set of points where $f'$ vanishes?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I am trying to determine necessary and sufficient constraints on the set of roots of a positive derivative $f'(x) \geqslant 0$ that determine whether $f$ is *strictly increasing* or just *increasing*.

Now, in high school I learned that

> If $f'(x) \geqslant 0$ for all $x$, and $f'(x)=0$ has finitely-many solutions, then $f$ is *strictly increasing*.

While this is a useful statement, I realise that the condition on $f'$ is *necessary* but certainly not *sufficient*. Indeed, it is easy to construct a strictly-increasing function whose derivative vanishes on a countably-infinite set of points (take for instance $f(x)=\int_0^x \sin^2{t}\ \mathrm{d}t$).

In fact, it is even possible to construct a strictly-increasing function whose derivative vanishes over an *uncountable* set. Here's a construction I came up with:

> Let $\mathcal{C} \subset [0,1]$ be the [Cantor set.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set) Define $I:[0,1]\to \left\{0,1\right\}$ such that $I(x)=0$ if $x \in \mathcal{C}$ and $I(x)=1$ if $x \notin \mathcal{C}.$ Then define $$f(x)=\int_0^x I(t)\ \mathrm{d}t, \qquad \ \ \ 0 \leqslant x \leqslant 1.$$ Since $\mathcal{C}$ is measure-zero, it is not hard to show that $I(x)$ has measure-zero discontinuity and hence that $f(x)$ is a well-defined integral in the Riemann sense. Further, one can show that $f(x)$ is strictly increasing, and $f'(x)=0$ for all $x\in \mathcal{C}$, which is an uncountable set.

I suspect that the necessary and sufficient condition for $f$ to be strictly-increasing is that the set where $f'$ vanishes must be nowhere dense:

> **Proposition.** Let $f$ be a differentiable function with $f'(x) \geqslant 0$ for all $x$, and let $S$ be the set of points where $f'$ vanishes. Then $f$ is strictly-increasing iff $S$ is nowhere-dense.

Here is my proposed proof:

> **Proof.** Equivalently, we prove the negation of the statement, namely that $f$ is locally-constant on some interval iff it some nonempty subset of $S$ is dense:
>
> $(\Rightarrow)$ If $f$ is locally-constant on some interval, call it $J$, then $f'(x)=0$ for $x \in J$ hence $S \cap J \subseteq S$ is dense since it is an interval.

However I am not able to prove the statement in the other direction. Assuming that my proposition is true, can someone help me out on the proof? If the statement *isn't* true, then what would be a possible counter-example? And what would be the characterisation of $S$?

Comment: Your construction of a function whose derivative vanishes on the Cantor set is not valid. Note that since the Cantor set has measure 0, $I(t) = 1$ almost everywhere, and hence $f(x) = x$. Also, if $f$ is differentiable everywhere, its derivative satisfies the intermediate value property, which $I(t)$ clearly does not.

Comment: @Jeffrey Dawson : Surely if $f(x) = x then we could take derivatives on both sides to get $f'(x)=1$ which isn't always true...

Comment: @user1892304 : I think your mistake is the assumption that we can use the fundamental theorem of calculus even when integrating discontinuous functions, which is not true.  In particular, it is not true that $f'(x) = I(x)$. Rather, since $f(x)=x$, we get $f'(x)=1$ for all $x \in [0,1]$.

Comment: @Michael What I don't understand, is that I was under the impression that the FTC holds whenever a function is Riemann-integrable...

Comment: It can't be true in that generality (For the Riemann integral and a derivative existing everywhere) since derivatives have the Intermediate Value property, while a general Riemann integrable function does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an alternative necessary and sufficient condition.

Claim:  Suppose  $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a differentiable function with $f’(x)\geq 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.  Then $f$ is strictly increasing if and only if on every interval $[a,b]$ with $a<b$, there is a point $c \in (a,b)$ such that $f’(c)>0$.

Proof:  Suppose $f$ is strictly increasing.  Let $a,b$ be real numbers such that $a<b$.  Then $f(a)<f(b)$. The intermediate value theorem implies there is a $c \in (a,b)$ such that $f’(c) = \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}>0$.

Now suppose $f$ is such that on every interval $[a,b]$ with $a<b$, there is a point $c \in (a,b)$ such that $f’(c)>0$.  Fix any real numbers $a,b$ such that $a<b$.  We want to show $f(a)<f(b)$. Let $c \in (a,b)$ be a number such that $f'(c)>0$. 
By definition of derivative, we have for all sufficiently small $h>0$: 
$$ \frac{f(c+h)-f(c)}{h}  >0$$
Hence, there is an $h>0$ such that $a < c < c+h < b$ and $f(c+h)-f(c) > 0$ and so: 
$$ f(a) \overset{(a)}{\leq} f(c) < f(c+h) \overset{(b)}{\leq} f(b) $$
where (a) and (b) hold because $f$ is nondecreasing. $\Box$

Comment: Equivalently, the set of roots of $f'$ is totally disconnected.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you

Comment: It is still not clear if there is an example of a strictly increasing differentiable function $f$  where the set of points with zero derivative is dense. Say, can the function have $f’(r)=0$ for every rational number $r$, but still be strictly increasing?

Comment: @Michael Yes, there is such an example. You could probably find it on google.

Comment: @zhw. I couldn't find one with Google, could you perhaps provide a link or reference?