# zeros of derivative and increasing function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ be a differentiable function. Is it true that $f$ is strictly increasing on $\mathbb R$ if and only if $f'(x) \geq 0$ on $\mathbb R$ and the set $X = \{x \in \mathbb{R} \,| \, f'(x) = 0\}$ is countable?

Comment: By increasing do you mean *strictly increasing*?

Comment: i doubt it, since strictly increasing would imply that f'(x) cannot equal 0.

Comment: I suspect OP means monotone increasing.

Comment: @jacobbradley That's not true. $f(x) = x^3$ is strictly increasing but $f'(0) = 0$. I doubt that the OP means nondecreasing, as $f(x) = 0$ would be a trivial counterexample.

Comment: oh yeah ofcourse, my bad. I'd say it would be true if the question was asking about strictly increasing then, since any countable points where f'(x) = 0 would mean that there must be an infinite number of reals in between them

Comment: I edit it. So it is strictly increasing

Comment: This may be of use: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1999622/169852

Comment: I believe you can get the middle thirds Cantor set as the zero set of the derivative of such a function by integration from $0$ to $x$ of the distance to the Cantor set. This gives an example for $f:[0,\infty) \rightarrow {\mathbb R},$ which can easily be extended to a strictly increasing differentiable function (with nonnegative derivative) on all of ${\mathbb R}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $f$ is differentiable and strictly increasing. Then yes, we must have $f'\ge 0$ everywhere. However, we can have $f'=0$ on an uncountable set, in fact a set of positive measure.

Example: Let $U$ be an open set containing the rationals, with $m(U)<1.$ Let $E=\mathbb R\setminus U.$ Then $E$ is closed. Define

$$f(x)=\int_0^x d(t,E)\,dt.$$

Since $d(t,E)$ is continuous, $f'(x) = d(x,E)$ everywhere. We thus have $f'=0$ on $E$ and $f'>0$ on $U.$

Now $m(E)=\infty$ and hence is uncountable. The fact that $f'>0$ on the open dense set $U$ implies $f$ is strictly increasing, and we have our example.

Comment: if $Q={q_1,q_2,...}$, then $U=\cup _{n=1} ^\infty (q_n - \frac {1} {2^n} , q_n + \frac {1} {2^n})$?

Comment: That's the idea; you may want to shrink those intervals a bit.

Comment: +1, I like this answer better than any of the ones to the question to which this one was duped.

Comment: @Bungo Thanks for your comment. Strangely, someone downvoted it.

Answer (score -2):

Edit: the op has edited the question to strictly increasing from simply increasing thus my answer is no longer valid. I think this isn't true and here is why, Take $f(x) = -x^2$ when $x<0$, $f(x) = 0$ when $x \in [0,1]$ and $f(x) = x^2-1$ when $x>1$, this function is clearly continuous, differentiable and increasing (not strictly). Now for the set of points between [0,1] f'(x) = 0, but x is an element of the reals so any closed interval such as [0,1] is uncountable.