# Suppose $f$ and $g$ are strictly convex functions and $f$ is increasing. Can $(f\circ g)^{\prime \prime}$ ever equal $0$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, convex-analysis

**Edit:** Ah, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1999622/754927) seems to answer my concerns. Take that Spivak, you big cheater!

**Original post:**
This concerns a problem in Calculus by Michael Spivak. Specifically 3rd edition, Chapter 11 Appendix, Problem 5.

I'll give the full problem for context. My question concerns the last part (c). Please note: this concerns *strictly* convex functions. Spivak's convention is for "convex" to mean "strictly convex" unless otherwise specified.

Problem 4 (referenced in part (a)) shows that $f$ is convex on an interval if and only if for all $x$ and $y$ in the interval we have
$$f(tx + (1-t)y)<tf(x) + (1-t)f(y)\text{, for }0<t<1.$$
This is not used for part (c) but it's included here for completeness.

> Chapter 11 Appendix, 5. (a) Prove that if $f$ and $g$ are convex and $f$ is increasing, then $f\circ g$ is convex. (It will be easiest to use Problem 4.)
>
> (b) Give an example where $g\circ f$ is not convex
>
> (c) Suppose that $f$ and $g$ are twice differentiable. Give another proof of the result of part (a) by considering second derivatives.

For part (c) I have:

$$(f\circ g)^{\prime}(x) = f^{\prime}(g(x))\cdot g^{\prime}(x)$$
$$(f\circ g)^{\prime\prime}(x) = f^{\prime\prime}(g(x))\cdot [g^{\prime}(x)]^2 + f^{\prime}(g(x))\cdot g^{\prime\prime}(x)$$

If $f$ and $g$ are convex, twice differentiable, and $f$ is increasing, we know that

- $f^{\prime} > 0$, except possibly at the leftmost edge of the interval, if such a point exists. This is because $f^{\prime} \geq 0$ and $f^{\prime}$ is increasing.
- $[g^{\prime}]^2 > 0$ except possibly at a single point.
- $f^{\prime\prime}$ and $g^{\prime\prime}\geq 0$. Furthermore, they cannot be $0$ over an interval. **They can maybe be zero at distinct points?**

Taking this all together I see that $(f\circ g)^{\prime\prime} \geq 0$. However, I don't think I've quite shown that it's greater than $0$.

Can $(f\circ g)^{\prime\prime} = 0$ at discrete points?

I think it cannot vanish over any interval, as this would require $g^{\prime\prime}$ to be zero over the interval, which in turn means $g^{\prime}$ is constant. But the discrete points thing, I'm not sure about.

The Answer Book solution says:

> (c) We have
> $$ (f\circ g)^{\prime} = (f^{\prime} \circ g)g^{\prime}$$
> $$ (f\circ g)^{\prime\prime} = (f^{\prime\prime}\circ g) g^{\prime 2} + (f^{\prime}\circ g)g^{\prime\prime}$$
>
> Since $f^{\prime\prime}, g^{\prime\prime}, g^{\prime} \geq 0$ it follows that $(f\circ g)^{\prime\prime} > 0$ if $f^{\prime} > 0$.

That last sentence seems false...

Comment: Is your concern that if $g$ is, e.g., a non-constant flat function at some point, then both $g'$ and $g''$ could be $0$ at that point, but $g$ is still convex, yes?

Comment: I guess I'm mostly bothered by the end of the Answer book solution. It seems to be skipping over some complications, with an argument that amounts to "if $a$, $b$, $c \geq 0$ and $d > 0$ then $ab + cd > 0$.

Comment: Thinking about it, $(f\circ g)^{\prime\prime} \geq 0$ and only zero at discrete points is probably enough to show $(f\circ g)^{\prime}$ is increasing, which is enough for convexity.